# Which packages are required for complete GNOME desktop / Snap integration?

Tags: gnome, snap, gnome-software

Which packages are required for the following user experience (including obvious ones like `gnome-shell`):

- I open Software and search for "keepassxc"
- The [KeePassXC snap](https://snapcraft.io/keepassxc/) appears
- I click to install, the package installs
- I open the GNOME overlay and search for "keepassxc"
- The KeePassXC application icon appears
- I click to launch, and the application launches

(KeePassXC is just an example here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Packages

- **gnome-software-plugin-snap**

  - gnome-software
  - libappstream-glib8
  - libc6
  - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  - libglib2.0-0
  - **libsnapd-glib1**

    - libjson-glib-1.0-0
    - libsoup2.4-1
    - **snapd**
    - **snapd-login-service** (no longer required once #1581713 resolved? - see link below)

### References

- gnome-software-plugin-snap package ([packages.ubuntu.com/artful](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/main/gnome-software-plugin-snap))
- gnome-software-plugin-snap request ([bugs.debian.org #877684](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877684))
- gnome-software bug ([bugs.launchpad.net #1581713](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1581713))